# how to cancel rounding decimals in symfony forms?

Tags: google-maps, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

In my entity, they are two fields: the latitude and the longitude.
There are declared as follows:

```
/**
 * @var decimal
 * @ORM\Column(name="lat", type="decimal", precision=18,scale=14, nullable=true)
 */
private $lat;    

/**
 * @var decimal
 * @ORM\Column(name="lng", type="decimal", precision=18,scale=14, nullable=true)
 */
private $lng;
```

I created a form and I entred the latitude and the longitude. This worked well.
The data I entred is: `lat= 36.80610237001900, lng=10.17517220741000`.

I checked in the data base and I find it as I entred (ie: `lat= 36.80610237001900, lng=10.17517220741000`)

But, when I wanted to edit the latitude and the longitude through the form, I got these values in the text inputs: `lat= 36.806, lng=10.175`.

The question is: how to make these text inputs display the exact values? How to specify the scale of the input texts? How to cancel rounding of decimals?

**NB:** This problem appreared after an update the bundles by the command:

```
php composer.phar update
```

If I am well remembering, doctrine/orm has been updated!

This is a part of my composer.json file:

```
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
```

I you have any ideas, don't hesitate!
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the solution!
When building the form, don't forget to specify the precision like this:

```
->add('lat','number', array('precision' => 14,'required' => false))
->add('lng','number', array('precision' => 14,'required' => false))
```